# Unable to connect the mongodb container to node container in docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, tcp, ip

I made 3 docker containers from 2 images in [this repo](https://github.com/Samar-080301/MernCrudApp) and 1 using MongoDB public image. I turned ON all three containers using `sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up`

`docker-compose.yaml` is:

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    image: samar080301/mern-frontend:1.0
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  backend:  
    image: samar080301/mern-backend:1.0
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

But the MongoDB couldn't connect with the node server and gave this error:

```
backend_1   | > crud-app@1.0.0 start /home/app
backend_1   | > node server.js
backend_1   | 
backend_1   | (node:18) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
backend_1   | (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
backend_1   | App running on port 5000
backend_1   | Error with the database! MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
backend_1   |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
backend_1   |   name: 'MongoNetworkError'
backend_1   | }]
backend_1   |     at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
backend_1   |     at Pool.emit (events.js:315:20)
backend_1   |     at /home/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:562:14
backend_1   |     at /home/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:995:11
backend_1   |     at /home/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7
backend_1   |     at callback (/home/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:280:5)
backend_1   |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:310:7)
backend_1   |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
backend_1   |     at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
backend_1   |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:84:8)
backend_1   |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
backend_1   | (node:18) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
backend_1   |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
backend_1   |   name: 'MongoNetworkError'
backend_1   | }]
```

Code of `backend/db.js`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// Allow Promises
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
// Connection
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db_test', { useNewUrlParser: true });
// Validation
mongoose.connection
  .once('open', () => console.log('Connected to the database!'))
  .on('error', err => console.log('Error with the database!', err));
```

Terminal Output of `docker inspect mongodb`:
[image]

Terminal output after adding the mongo uri as environment variable:

```
backend_1   | App running on port 5000
backend_1   | (node:19) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
backend_1   | (node:19) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

New error:

```
backend_1   | Error with the database! MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [merncrudapp_mongodb_1:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.23.0.3:27017
backend_1   |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
backend_1   |   name: 'MongoNetworkError'
backend_1   | }]
```

Comment: Please include logs from mongodb container too. The error says it is not started at the time backend connects to it. It could be just a race condition, as mongo requires some time to spin up and start listening on the port.

Answer (score 5):

When you run docker-compose up, the following [happens](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/):

1. A network called `MernCrudApp`(takes the default name of the directory) is created.
2. A container is created using the `frontend`'s configuration. It joins the network `MernCrudApp` under the name `frontend`.
3. A container is created using the `backend`'s configuration. It joins the network `MernCrudApp` under the name `backend`.
4. A container is created using `mongodb`’s configuration. It joins the network `MernCrudApp` under the name `mongodb`.

now if you use `mongodb://localhost:27017/db_test` to connect to the db, the node app will look for MongoDB in the backend container which you will get a connection error since it does not exist.

To remedy this, change the MongoDB connection string to `mongodb://mongodb:27017/db_test` so that it

**Aditional comments**
I would recommend the following to help solve some problems you might face in the future using the current configuration.

1. Add the connection string as an environment variable. This will make it easier for you to change the DB instances without rebuilding the container.
2. Since the backend application depends on the database add [`depend_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) on the docker-compose files so that the MongoDB container starts before the backend container

Comment: how can i add the connection string as env variable? Please tell me, actually I have just started learning docker

Comment: Let say `MONGO_URI` is the environment variable for MongoDB. Add a line in the docker file `ENV MONGO_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017/db_test`. once you build it you can change it on the docker-compose files. Find more info on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39597925/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-during-the-build-in-docker)

Comment: How can I pass that uri to my javascript connector code?

Comment: example `const mongo_uri = process.env.MONGO_URI` and then pass the variable when using the mongodb connect function `mongoose.connect(mongo_uri , { useNewUrlParser: true });`

Comment: I did it, you can check the updated code in Github and I have also updated the new error

Answer (score 3):

Try to connect not using `localhost` but a container name. So for example, if you want to connect to MongoDB from another container (in the same docker network) you can use `mongodb:27017`.
It should work.

Comment: i have added the code of DB connection, do I need to change the name over there?

Comment: Yes, please try to replace `localhost` with container name (in your configuration it is `mongodb`)

Comment: i did it, it gave me this error `Error with the database! { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mongodb mongodb:27017]`

Comment: should i do it 0.0.0.0:27017?

Comment: Hmm, you can try with `0.0.0.0` or `127.0.0.1` if it's still doesn't work, please 
do `docker ps` check ID of MongoDB container and then `docker inspect <container_id>` and then try to find IP address also please check if port is the same you want to reach.

Comment: i have added the output of the terminal in the question. Is the IP address correct?

Comment: Your container IP is 172.20.0.3 :)

Comment: but it's dynamic, I need a solution for that :-(

Answer (score 1):

Modify your backend/db.js code.

Your are getting error because when you mention '**localhost**' in code your container is trying to connect to backend container on port 2017 which not in use.

```
// Connection
//mongodb is a container name of mongo image
mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongodb:27017/db_test', { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

**Pro Tip -**
1)If you are in same docker network then use hostname or Docker Container Name to communicate/Link with each other.

2)Never use container IP address in code if IP's are not assign manually. Whenever you restart container it may change.

Comment: i tried both `mongodb://merncrudapp_mongodb_1:27017/db_test` and `mongodb://mongodb:27017/db_test`. But they both gave me error which i have added in the question as new error

Comment: Is your mongodb container running ? to check this use below command from your server. Command - telnet localhost 27017 if you are not able to telnet 27017 port then it means Mongodb container is not running.